# Select rows whose mappings are a subset of given input in a many-to-many mappings table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a many-to-many table with product and tag columns. How do I query for "Give me the list of products which have only one of these tags in their mapping"?

Input : '2,3,4' (This corresponds to tagid columns in Mappings table)

Output Expected : 3,4,5 (This corresponds to productid column. Products 3,4,5 have tags which are a subset (or a proper subset) of '2,3,4').

```html
-- Table: Product
+---------+-----------+
| productid | name      |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | HTC       |
|       2 | Nokia     |
|       3 | Samsung   |
|       4 | Motorolla |
|       5 | Apple     |
+---------+-----------+

-- Table: Mappings
+------+-----------+
| tagid| productid |
+------+-----------+
|    1 |       1   |
|    1 |       2   |
|    2 |       1   |
|    2 |       3   |
|    3 |       1   |
|    3 |       4   |
|    4 |       5   |
+------+-----------+

-- Table: Tags
+------+-------+
| tagid  | name  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | blue   |
|    2 | black  |
|    3 | pink   |
|    4 | gold   |
+------+-------+
```

EDIT :

Explanation of Expected output: 
Input tagIds - {2,3,4} . 
For tagId 2, in mappings table we have mapped productIds { 1,3 }.
tagId 3 has a mapping { 1, 4} and tagId 4 has mapping  { 5 }. So the combined list of productIds is {1,3,4,5}.
But now the productId 1 has a tagId 1 associated with it which is not in the input list of tagIds . So the final output should be {3, 4 , 5}. Hope this clears things up.

Comment: So you want all products that have all mappings in your input tagids? Simple as that?

Comment: added solution for that in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like?:

```
select products.productid, products.name
from products inner join mappings on products.productid = mappings.productid
where mappings.tagid in (2,3,4) -- 2,3,4 is your input
group by products.productid , products.name
having count(*) = 1
```

with the edit:

```
select products.productid, product.name
from products
where not exists 
(
    select * from mappings
    where products.productid = mappings.productid and not mappings.tagid in (2,3,4)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?  It works in MS-SQL.  I don't have a mysql database instance running at the moment.

```
select * from products
where (select count(*) from mappings 
       where products.productid=mappings.productid
       AND mappings.tagid in (2,3,4)) = 1
```

@Florian's solution will also work if you add a GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT products.productid,products.productname,count(*)
FROM products
INNER JOIN mappings on products.productid = mappings.productid
AND mappings.tagid in (2,3,4)
GROUP BY products.productid,products.productname
HAVING count(*)=1
```

Comment: thank you i added it. pretty sure you dont need the aggregate function in the the list of result fields.

Comment: Cool.  I'm working off my knowledge of MS SQL, where any aggregation clause will choke if there is anything in the select clause that is neither an aggregate function nor in the GROUP BY clause.  THanks for the info.

Comment: @Florian, sorry, misread that.  No, don't need the aggregate function at all.  Also, I missed the tagid filter.